# How do we know there is no basis for the ideal $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ as a $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, algebraic-number-theory

> How do we know there is no basis for the ideal $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ as a $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$-module?

We know $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ is generated by $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$, but these two elements are not independent since $2(1+\sqrt{-5})+(1+\sqrt{-5})(-2)=0$.

But how do we know there does not exist some other two elements that generate and are independent?

Comment: They are not independent over $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, but they are independent over $\Bbb{Z}$. In fact no two elements $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ can be independent over $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ because $b\cdot a+(-a)\cdot b=0$.

Comment: I guess the point is that it is not generated (freely) by a single element. Or, in other words, the ideal is not principal.

Comment: This definition might be wrong and/or it might not apply: http://planetmath.org/basisofidealinalgebraicnumberfield If I'm understanding correctly, every ideal in the given ring has a basis, and the length of that basis depends on the degree of the ring. So the basis of $\langle 2, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$ would consist of two numbers (since $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is of degree 2) and be something like $\{2, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \}$.

Answer (score 5):

In a commutative ring $A$, any two elements $a,b\neq0$ are linearly dependent over $A$: $ab-ba=0$.